# coloring text in a time when condition is fulfilled

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to coloring text on green or red when condition ( if ) is fulfilled.

There is my function getAll()

```
            function getAllTasks() {
                $http.get('db_files/tasksDB.php').then(function (response) {
                    $scope.tasks = response.data;
                    $scope.tasks = response.data.map(function (item) {
                        var millisDiff = (new Date(item.deadline) - new Date(item.task_start));
                        item.dayDiff = Math.floor(millisDiff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
                        $scope.color = function () {
                            return (item.dayDiff < 1) ? 'red' : 'green';
                        };
                        return item;
                    });
                });
            }
```

And there is part of my table where I want to color text.
Example below don't works.

```
<td md-cell><font color="{{task.color}}">{{ task.dayDiff }}</font></td>
```

I also tried like that but it always coloring on green or on red.

```
<td md-cell><font color="{{color}}">{{ task.dayDiff }}</font></td>
```

I want to do something like that: If one day left then color text on red else color on green.

Comment: Check the documentation - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle there is an example with text color

Comment: post the `response.data` json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the color function to item object, so you could call it in the view.

```
<td md-cell><font color="{{task.color()}}">{{ task.dayDiff }}</font></td>
```

```js
function getAllTasks() {
  $http.get('db_files/tasksDB.php').then(function(response) {
    $scope.tasks = response.data;
    $scope.tasks = response.data.map(function(item) {
      var millisDiff = (new Date(item.deadline) - new Date(item.task_start));
      item.dayDiff = Math.floor(millisDiff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
      item.color = function() {
        return (item.dayDiff < 1) ? 'red' : 'green';
      };
      return item;
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: is always green I did before $scope.col = $scope.color(); also with {{color()}} is always green

Comment: It works!. Thank you man you 100% right. I did like that task.colors but i forgot about (). Thank you

Comment: Great! glad to hear that.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ng-style` directive to assign styles from the controller. here is sample demo

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope){

  $scope.itemArr = [{  
     "id":"521",
     "username":"defus",
     "task":"test",
     "dept":"test",
     "status":"Otwarte",
     "task_start":"2017-02-26 11:47:29",
     "task_end":"0000-00-00 00:00:00",
     "task_time":null,
     "deadline":"2017-02-28"
  }]
 
  
 $scope.itemArr =   $scope.itemArr.map(function(item) {
    var millisDiff = (new Date(item.deadline) - new Date(item.task_start));
    item.dayDiff = Math.floor(millisDiff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    $scope.color = (item.dayDiff > 1) ? 'red' : 'green'; 
    return item;
  });
   console.log($scope.itemArr)
   console.log($scope.color)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
<font ng-style="{'color':color}">working</font>
</div>
```

Comment: Your example works great but I want to do something like that. I have to choose between red or green like here http://codepen.io/defuzer/pen/NpWeMX

Comment: so you need to change the color based on the if condition

Comment: @Sacgilia ranawaka You did exactly what I had in my answer but in other way. Still doesn't work and everything is green

Comment: can u post the response data array

Comment: Tasks/data array:  
Array[12]
0
:
Object
1
:
Object
2
:
Object
3
:
Object
4
:
Object
5
:
Object
6
:
Object
7
:
Object
8
:
Object
9
:
Object
10
:
Object
11
:
Object
length
:
12
and example data
8
:
Object
dayDiff
:
37
deadline
:
"2017-04-05"
dept
:
"test"
id
:
"529"
status
:
"Otwarte"
task
:
"hghj"
task_end
:
"0000-00-00 00:00:00"
task_start
:
"2017-02-26 12:05:58"
task_time
:
null
username
:
"defus"

Comment: `console.log(JSON.stringify( response.data[0]))` add this line add post the result of this console

Comment: JSON:  {"id":"521","username":"defus","task":"test","dept":"test","status":"Otwarte","task_start":"2017-02-26 11:47:29","task_end":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","task_time":null,"deadline":"2017-02-28"}

Comment: check the demo again

Comment: Output of console.log("Colors: ",$scope.color); is Colors:  red

Comment: demo shows color green. try with a different ternary condition

Comment: Thank you for help buddy but stack fan solver my problem. Anyway thank you very much.